# Kafka Producer can not reconnect and refresh metada after broker address changed

Tags: apache-kafka

I run Kafka with k8s, using k8s NodePort which not change after pod rebuild for Kafka client to fetch topic metadata. Pod Ip and Node Ip are accessible outside.

Kafka version: 2.11-0.11.0.2

Test script:

```
bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh \
   --print-metrics \
   --topic $TOPIC \
   --num-records 10000000 \
   --record-size 500 \
   --throughput 10 \
   --producer-props acks=1 metadata.max.age.ms=10000 \
   bootstrap.servers=$KAFKA_0 \
   buffer.memory=67108864 \
   batch.size=8196
```

The output:

```
52 records sent, 10.3 records/sec (0.00 MB/sec), 14.6 ms avg latency, 325.0 ms max latency.
50 records sent, 10.0 records/sec (0.00 MB/sec), 1.5 ms avg latency, 2.0 ms max latency.
50 records sent, 10.0 records/sec (0.00 MB/sec), 1.4 ms avg latency, 2.0 ms max latency.
50 records sent, 10.0 records/sec (0.00 MB/sec), 1.3 ms avg latency, 2.0 ms max latency.
51 records sent, 10.2 records/sec (0.00 MB/sec), 1.2 ms avg latency, 2.0 ms max latency.
50 records sent, 10.0 records/sec (0.00 MB/sec), 1.1 ms avg latency, 2.0 ms max latency.
50 records sent, 10.0 records/sec (0.00 MB/sec), 5.3 ms avg latency, 113.0 ms max latency.
50 records sent, 10.0 records/sec (0.00 MB/sec), 1.1 ms avg latency, 2.0 ms max latency.
50 records sent, 10.0 records/sec (0.00 MB/sec), 0.9 ms avg latency, 2.0 ms max latency.
[2019-12-05 10:24:41,072] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 14 (/10.197.129.81:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2019-12-05 10:24:41,128] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 12 (/10.197.128.77:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2019-12-05 10:24:41,175] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 14 (/10.197.129.81:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2019-12-05 10:24:41,225] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 12 (/10.197.128.77:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2019-12-05 10:24:41,403] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 14 (/10.197.129.81:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2019-12-05 10:24:41,410] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 12 (/10.197.128.77:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2019-12-05 10:24:41,778] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 14 (/10.197.129.81:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2019-12-05 10:24:41,807] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 12 (/10.197.128.77:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2019-12-05 10:24:42,567] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 14 (/10.197.129.81:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2019-12-05 10:24:42,680] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 12 (/10.197.128.77:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2019-12-05 10:24:43,417] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 14 (/10.197.129.81:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2019-12-05 10:24:43,709] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 12 (/10.197.128.77:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

26 records sent, 0.2 records/sec (0.00 MB/sec), 4616.4 ms avg latency, 120000.0 ms max latency.
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 15 record(s) for reconnect-test-2:120000 ms has passed since batch creation
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 15 record(s) for reconnect-test-2:120000 ms has passed since batch creation
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 15 record(s) for reconnect-test-2:120000 ms has passed since batch creation
```

The problem:

```
After rebuilding the Kafka broker pod, pod IP changed, NodePort not change, the Kafka producer can not reconnect, and print the warning log forever. But there is no problem after restart the test script.
```

Comment: You need to make sure the Kafka advertised IP remains constant, or advertise service names instead

Comment: You are right, We need to make sure at least one Kafka advertised IP remains constant for metadata update. Kafka producer will not reload metadata with BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG.